# Maven 3 Profile Properties - enhancement or bug?

Tags: maven-2, maven, maven-3

In Maven 2, I was able to set profile properties like these:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>test</id>
        <properties>
            <region>test</region>
            <application-url>http://localhost:8080/myTestApp</application-url>
            <cookie-name>TestCookie</cookie-name>
        </properties>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>production</id>
        <properties>
            <region>production</region>
            <application-url>http://prodserver/myProductionApp</application-url>
            <cookie-name>ProductionCookie</cookie-name>
        </properties>
    </profile>
<profiles>
```

At compile time Maven would replace these configuration values in my spring beans.  For instance, if I had a spring bean defined like this:

```
<bean id="cookie-name" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg value="${cookie-name}"/>
</bean>
```

and I specified `-P test` when i build the project, Maven would set the set the bean to look like

```
<bean id="cookie-name" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg value="TestCookie"/>
</bean>
```

and when I specified `-P production`, maven again replaced the text with the correct property

```
<bean id="cookie-name" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg value="ProductionCookie"/>
</bean>
```

As the number of environments and customers we support has increased, I've been taking more advantage of this functionality.

I've tried to upgrade to Maven 3, but it seems like this behavior has disappeared or is broken.  I can't seem to find what it has been replaced by.

Anyone have any insights on how or if I can upgrade to Maven3 while preserving this behavior?

Comment: Did you defined the profiles in the pom or in profiles.xml file?

Comment: I define the profiles directly in the POM.

Answer (score 4):

> I've tried to upgrade to Maven 3, but it seems like this behavior has disappeared or is broken. I can't seem to find what it has been replaced by.

*Resources filtering* just works fine with Maven 3. Given the following project structure:

```
.
├── pom.xml
└── src
    ├── main
    │   ├── java
    │   │   └── com
    │   │       └── stackoverflow
    │   │           └── App.java
    │   └── resources
    │       └── beans.xml
    └── test
        └── java
            └── com
                └── stackoverflow
                    └── AppTest.java
```

With the following `pom.xml`:

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
  <artifactId>Q4206883</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  ...
  <build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
      </resource>
    </resources>
  </build>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>test</id>
      <properties>
        <region>test</region>
        <application-url>http://localhost:8080/myTestApp</application-url>
        <cookie-name>TestCookie</cookie-name>
      </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>production</id>
      <properties>
        <region>production</region>
        <application-url>http://prodserver/myProductionApp</application-url>
        <cookie-name>ProductionCookie</cookie-name>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

And where `beans.xml` contains:

```
<bean id="cookie-name" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg value="${cookie-name}"/>
</bean>
```

Running maven with any of the profiles e.g.:

```
$ mvn -P test process-resources 
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
...
```

Produces the expected result:

```
$ cat target/classes/beans.xml 
<bean id="cookie-name" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg value="TestCookie"/>
</bean>
```

Tested with:

```
$ mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.0 (r1004208; 2010-10-04 13:50:56+0200)
Java version: 1.6.0_22
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.22/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux" version: "2.6.35-22-generic" arch: "i386" Family: "unix"
```

If this is not what you get, please provide some pieces allowing to reproduce.

Answer (score 4):

Can only post 1 link at a time and apparently only one answer every 3 minutes :-(

http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MRESOURCES-117

Answer (score 2):

The latest released version (2.4.3) of the maven-resources-plugin is broken.

http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MRESOURCES-104